# How to turn off 'new command window spawning' in the newest spyder when running another program from python

Tags: python, subprocess, spyder

I spend a lot of time running programs from python using the `subprocess` module. One of my scripts uses the `check_call` command to run a program from the command line around 600 times. Today I updated to Spyder 3 and when I run this script I get a pop up which looks like this
[image]

This stays for the duration of the program (a few seconds) then disappears but then another appears to replace it as my programs uses the `check_call` command again. This behavior is very disruptive as it means I can't just run a long program in the background on my machine whilst working on something else. Also this was never a problem on the old version of Spyder I had. Does anybody know how to turn this very annoying behavior off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder dev here*) If I'm not mistaken, now you need to pass the parameter `shell=True` to all `subprocess` commands you're using to avoid this problem.